# public static variable in library which is mapped to server

Tags: java, webserver, classloader

if there is a library which is mapped to server lib and it have one class which have one variable as public static.
As per my understaning
1. on that server it will be one single copy.

1. if that server is mapped with some cluster having more servers then again that static instance will be copied to cluster common memory and then again mentioned as single instance in all the servers.
2. now if there is more than 1 cluster then all clusters will have its own copy of that static instance.

Can some validate these three points.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mutable statics are bad for all sorts of reasons - AVOID!!

You will have one value of a static field per class. Classes loaded by separate `ClassLoader`s are different classes. No instance is shared between processes. Therefore, static field values are not shared between processes. In terms of servlet containers, the application scope is not shared between processes either.